# Install aptana plugin for eclipse along side with Jboss Tools

Tags: eclipse

While trying to install Aptana Web Development Tools via Install New Software feature of Eclipse, this error occur:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Web Development Tools 1.2.7.024747 (com.aptana.ide.feature.feature.group 1.2.7.024747)
  Software currently installed: JBoss Tools JSF 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-2220-B66 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-2220-B66)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Mozilla XPCOM Eclipse plugin 1.9.2.16 (org.mozilla.xpcom 1.9.2.16)
    org.mozilla.xpcom 1.8.1.3-20070320
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Web Development Tools 1.2.7.024747 (com.aptana.ide.feature.feature.group 1.2.7.024747)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.xul.feature.group [1.2.7.024747]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Embedded Firefox Support (XUL-based) 1.2.7.024747 (com.aptana.ide.feature.xul.feature.group 1.2.7.024747)
    To: org.mozilla.xpcom [1.8.1.3-20070320]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Tools JSF 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-2220-B66 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-2220-B66)
    To: org.jboss.tools.vpe.feature.feature.group 3.3.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-1952-B75 (org.jboss.tools.vpe.feature.feature.group 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-1952-B75)
    To: org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner [3.4.0.Final-v20121205-1952-B75]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Browser (XULRunner) Plug-in 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-1952-B75 (org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner 3.4.0.Final-v20121205-1952-B75)
    To: bundle org.mozilla.xpcom 1.9.1
```

Is there anyway to install aptana along side with jboss tools, because i need the jquery auto completion in aptana plugin